# Image classification with species and individual ID

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm new to deep learning and I'm trying out a challenge that where I need to classify species of whale. The requirement is that I need to match 5 individual ids with an image evaluated with map@5

I'm having trouble with how I should process the data. The csv has a structure like this for the training set:

[train_csv head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf5Qi.png)

The test set does not include species name and for each image in the test set I may predict up to 5 individual ids. For every new individual in the test set a prediction of `new_individual` should be made.

Right now I'm just trying to figure out If I need to even include the species column while processing the data on the test csv and images.

I plan on using tensorflow during this.

EDIT: Individual IDs correlate to species. There are 30 species and 15587 individual ids. There is a total of 51033 images.

Comment: could you explain some more what your problem is? are you having a error with your code? are you wondering about what you should do in practice? please be specific. is the individual id the only form of label for the data? also, are you doing the HappyWhale competition on Kaggle? there are plenty of baselines for questions like this. the image you provided looks like the one used in the competition.